# Android app crashes when showing image in imageview with imageUri from internal storage

Tags: android, image, kotlin, runtime-error, android-permissions

I am making an Android app, where the user can keep track of pieces of street art in their city. The app consists of a Main activity, which contains a recycler view to display the image and string, stored in each ArtPiece object, and it contains an Add button, to add ArtPiece objects to the list.
When the user clicks Add, the AddActivity is opened and they can input a string and have a button Choose image, which opens files and they select an image. The uri of that image is then stored as a string in the object. Then the user clicks Save and the object is created, saved to the list, and displayed in the Main Activity in the recycler view. This all works perfectly.

Then the user can click a item in recycler view, which opens the AddActivity in EDIT mode, and the user can edit the properties of the object he clicked, so the string and the image. If the user clicks Choose image again, he can select a image, but if he doesnt select a new one, then the uri string doesnt change. Now when user clicks Save, if they have choosen a new image, it works fine, but if they didnt and uri remained the same, there is an exception and app craches.
Here is the exception: *java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.media.MediaDocumentsProvider from ProcessRecord{daaa4a9 9467:com.example.graffititracker/u0a186} (pid=9467, uid=10186) requires that you obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs*

Here is my code in AddActivity, but as I have said, if the user doesnt change the image, it doesnt work:

```
class AddActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityAddBinding

    private var selectedImageUri: Uri? = null

        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            binding = ActivityAddBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
            setContentView(binding.root)

            val mode = intent.getStringExtra("MODE")
            val position = intent.getIntExtra("position", -1)
            var piece = ArtPiece("", Date(1,1,2020), "", "")

            // If ADD has been opened in EDIT mode, load values into fields
            if(mode == "EDIT"){
                piece = app.myCollection.getPiece(position)

                binding.txtName.setText(piece.name)
                binding.btnAddPhoto.setText(R.string.btn_ChangePhoto)
            }

            binding.btnSave.setOnClickListener(object: View.OnClickListener{
                override fun onClick(v: View?) {
                    if(binding.txtName.text.isNotEmpty()){
                        val data = Intent()
                        data.putExtra("name", binding.txtName.text.toString())

                        // if in edit mode, image is set to new selected image, or stays the same as before
                        if(mode == "EDIT"){
                            data.putExtra("position", position)

                            if(selectedImageUri != null)
                                data.putExtra("imageUri", selectedImageUri?.toString())
                            else
                                data.putExtra("imageUri", piece.image)
                        }
                        else{
                            if(selectedImageUri != null)
                                data.putExtra("imageUri", selectedImageUri?.toString())
                            else
                                data.putExtra("imageUri", "")
                        }

                        setResult(RESULT_OK, data)
                        finish()
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(this@AddActivity, "Please fill out all the spaces!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                }
            })

            // ADD PHOTO BUTTON
            binding.btnAddPhoto.setOnClickListener(object: View.OnClickListener{
                override fun onClick(v: View?) {
                    // ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT instead of ACTION_PICK for permission reasons (app crashes when editing if using ACTION_PICK)
                    val galleryIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
                    startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, 1)
                }
            })
        }

        override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
            if(requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                data?.data?.let{
                    selectedImageUri = it
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

And here is code in recycler view adapter to display objects in the rows:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val piece = app.myCollection.getPiece(position)

        if(piece.image != "")
            holder.imageView.setImageURI(Uri.parse(piece.image))
        else
            holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.resource_default)

        holder.tvName.text = piece.name
        holder.tvDate.text = piece.date.toString()

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener{
            listener.onItemClick(piece)
        }

        holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener {
            longClickListener.onItemLongClick(piece)
            true
        }
    }
```

In my manifest, i have this permission:
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />`

Comment: As soon as you get an image file uri you should take persistable uri permission in order to be able to use that uri later again.

Comment: `In my manifest, i have this permission:` You do not need that permission to let the user select images.